# 2sxc - "The server failed to resume the transaction" with multiple webApi.post

Tags: sql-server, 2sxc

When trying to use multiple successive webApi.post inside a for loop,

```
for (i = 1; i <= indexLoops; i++) {
    $2sxc(@Dnn.Module.ModuleID).webApi.post('app/auto/content/entity', {}, newItem);
}
```

if it repeats 2-3 times, it works fine, but if "i" reaches 4+, it will give this error:

```
The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:d100000001. The transaction active in this session has been committed or aborted by another session.
```

Creating a 200ms delayed loop fixes it.

Is this a SQL server limitation or a 2scx controller issue? Can it affect users if they both attempt a post simultaneously?

Comment: As of today, all data is cached for reading - and when items are created, this cache is refreshed - which takes a moment. Since 99% of all use cases are 99% reading and very little writing, this is optimal. BUT for power writing it's not optimal. We're planning on supporting this early next year, but till then you could either use your buffer, or write such data to a sql-table and use the sqldatasource when you need to read it, not caching.

Comment: Guess I'll wait for next year then :)